# Tool to work with archive?

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1

I need the archive tool that in **dired mode** that can:

1. work with many archive: zip, 7z, gzip and so on
2. create archive from selected files  in dired mode and folders (with subfolders)
3. edit files INSIDE exist archive
4. copy/move files from selected files in dired  mode to EXIST archive
5. extract archive to desire path
6. view files inside archive
7. delete **selected** files/folders from archive

Can you advise me some archive tool?

Comment: I suggest installing [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) and reading about how to integrate that with the native Emacs under MS Windows, so that Emacs will be able to use any of those tools.

Comment: @phils Pityingly `archive-mode` does not fulfill all specifications given in the question. For an instance moving files from dired into the archive is not supported for zip files. (There are many more restrictions.)

Answer (score 1):

Emacs opens compressed files and save/compress by default:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compressed-Files.html#Compressed-Files

> Emacs automatically uncompresses compressed files when you visit them, and automatically recompresses them if you alter them and save them. Emacs recognizes compressed files by their file names. File names ending in ‘.gz’ indicate a file compressed with gzip. Other endings indicate other compression programs.
>
> Automatic uncompression and compression apply to all the operations in which Emacs uses the contents of a file. This includes visiting it, saving it, inserting its contents into a buffer, loading it, and byte compiling it.

As for archives (tar), look at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Archives.html#File-Archives

Emacs then starts `tar-mode` (similar to dired).

Look also [archive-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ArchiveMode)